# Skipping validation if object is created from a certain method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, omniauth

I'm trying to set up Omniauth login for Twitter/FB. I created my own authentication system that validates for password and email upon creation of a user. However, I do not want to validate for password or email when my users log in through Twitter/Fb.

I created a user attribute called omniauth_login. I am using it as a boolean to test whether validation is required or not in my should_validate_password? method.

User.rb

```
attr_accessor :password, :updating_password, :omniauth_login
validates_presence_of :password, :if => :should_validate_password?
validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :should_validate_password?

def should_validate_password?
  (updating_password || new_record?) && !(self.omniauth_login == 'true')
end

def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  create! do |user|
    user.provider = auth["provider"]
    user.uid = auth["uid"]
    user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
  end
end
```

Here is my controller used to create the user:

sessions_controller.rb

```
def omniauth_create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.new
  user.omniauth_login = 'true'
  user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) ||         
         User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to user
end
```

When I try to create a new user by logging in via twitter, I still get the validation error:

```
Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email is not valid.
```

**How do I skip validation of password and email if my object is being created in the create_with_omniauth method?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you have two separate instances of User, one that has omniauth_login set to 'true', and another that does not. The first is gotten from

```
user = User.new
user.omniauth_login = 'true'
```

The second is

```
User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
```

. The second instance created here doesn't have omniauth_login set to 'true', so it still runs the validations. Try this instead

```
user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth["provider"], auth["uid"]) ||         
 User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
```

and in create_with_omniauth, add `user.omniauth_login = 'true'`
.